# haw to insert an Image of base64 from database to recycleView

Tags: android

I'm building a recycle view that gets API information, It works fine but until now I used an Image from my drawable folder but I need to change it with a base64 (in form String) Image from my API.

then guys how to change my code to make recycle get API image.

NewsItem.class

```
    public class NewsItem {

        String Title,Content,Date,type_col;
        int userPhoto;
        public  NewsItem(){

        }

        public NewsItem(String title, String content, String date, String type_col, int userPhoto) {
            Title = title;
            Content = content;
            Date = date;
            this.type_col = type_col;
            this.userPhoto = userPhoto;
        }

        public String getType_col() {
            return type_col;
        }

        public void setType_col(String type_col) {
            this.type_col = type_col;
        }

        public void setTitle(String title) {
            Title = title;
        }

        public void setContent(String content) {
            Content = content;
        }

        public void setDate(String date) {
            Date = date;
        }

        public void setUserPhoto(int userPhoto) {
            this.userPhoto = userPhoto;
        }

        public String getTitle() {
            return Title;
        }

        public String getContent() {
            return Content;
        }

        public String getDate() {
            return Date;
        }

        public int getUserPhoto() {
            return userPhoto;
        }
    }
```

newsadapter:

```
public class NewsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NewsAdapter.NewsViewHolder> {

    Context mContext;
    List<NewsItem> mData;

    public NewsAdapter(Context mContext, List<NewsItem> mData) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mData = mData;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public NewsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View layout = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.item_news,parent,false);

        return new NewsViewHolder(layout);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull NewsViewHolder newsViewHolder, int position) {
        //bind data
        newsViewHolder.tv_title.setText(mData.get(position).getTitle());
        newsViewHolder.tv_description.setText(mData.get(position).getContent());
        newsViewHolder.tv_date.setText(mData.get(position).getDate());
        newsViewHolder.tv_type_col.setText(mData.get(position).getType_col());
        newsViewHolder.img_user.setImageResource(mData.get(position).getUserPhoto());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    public class NewsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView tv_title,tv_description,tv_date,tv_type_col;
        ImageView img_user;

        public NewsViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tv_title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
            tv_description = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_description);
            tv_date = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_date);
            tv_type_col = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_type_col);
            img_user = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_user);
        }
    }
}
```

Main fragment:

```
RecyclerView NewsRecyclerview;
    NewsAdapter newsAdapter;
    List<NewsItem> mData;


 public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

NewsRecyclerview = root.findViewById(R.id.news_rv);
        mData = new ArrayList<>();

        getd("all");}

    private void getd(String selector){//, final GalleryFragment.MarkerLoadCallBack markerLoadCallBack
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Api.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()) //Here we are using the GsonConverterFactory to directly convert json data to object
                .build();

        Api api = retrofit.create(Api.class);

        Call<List<col>> call = api.getHeroes(selector);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<col>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<col>> call, Response<List<col>> response) {
                // mker = new ArrayList<>();
                List<col> colList = response.body();
                for (col c : colList) {
                    Log.d("image : ", c.getImagePath() + "");

                    mData.add(new NewsItem(c.getNom_col().toString(),"L'email de Client est:" + c.getEmailcol()+"\n" +  "La matricule est :     \n"+ "Créer par "+ c.getCreator() + "\n"  ,"le "+c.getDate_creation_col().toString(),"Type:" + c.getType(),R.drawable.t));
                }
                newsAdapter = new NewsAdapter(getContext(),mData);
                NewsRecyclerview.setAdapter(newsAdapter);
                NewsRecyclerview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

            }
```

The String form image is c.getImagePath()

Comment: What is in your base64 encoded string exactly?

Comment: `c.getImagePath()` contans the base64 encoded string

Comment: That is not the answer i'm waiting for. What is it that you encoded base64 exactly? If it was a path to an image then you would not have base64 encoded that path i think.

Comment: So whatis logged by this statement: `Log.d("image : ", c.getImagePath() + "");` ?

Comment: nope not a path I used `        col_photo.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
`
`        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
`
`        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
`
`        byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream .toByteArray();
        String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);`
before for change images to string so imagepath is the real image on string form

Comment: I logged image : just for testing the API works and the string comes from the server

Comment: So you encoded a png image. Where when did you do that? Pleas put all code in your post. Write a decent post where you start telling how you obtained image(s) and why you encode them. Remove that comment with code. We dont like to read code from comments. Do you?

Comment: `and the string comes from the server` ??? And where did you compress to png then? Pretty confusing.

Comment: ok I devlopper two apps and one send a string format image to nodeJs server and the second retrieve it

Answer (score 0):

Glide library support base 64 format. so you can use this library to bind your image via your path please see below link https://github.com/bumptech/glide for more information